# bash: use cat/grep with long argument list

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following structure in bash:

```
cat myfiles_* | grep "mystring" > summary.txt
```

If there are too many files, the command fails with "argument list too long".

Usually, one would use xargs to avoid the "argument list too long" error, but in this case the files have to be concatenated, so that is not an option.

Is there another way to filter "mystring" from a list of (too) many files?

Comment: find ... | xargs cat | grep ?

Comment: Why do you need `cat` in the first place? If the problem is that `grep` outputs the filenames when you give it a file list you can just supress that with the `-h` option (i.e. `find . -name "myfiles_*" -maxdepth 1|xargs grep -h "mystring" > summary.txt`). Besides: why is this a bash problem? Does it work in, say, zsh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to avoid the "argument list too long" error caused by bash's [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29):

```
find . -name 'myfiles_*' -type f -exec grep "mystring" {} \; > summary.txt
```

You can also provide `-maxdepth 1` option to `find`, in case you don't want to traverse subdirectories. This is compatible with your `cat myfiles_*` behaviour.

Comment: You could even use the `-exec ... +` construct to only spawn one `grep` for many many files.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `cat` with programs that reads data itself, try:

```
grep "mystring" myfiles_* > summary.txt
```

You can also try `awk`

```
awk '/mystring/' myfiles_* > summary.txt
```